# Java: createUser Constructor fails to create a file?

Tags: java, file, createfile

I've just learned to create and read from files and I'm practicing it by making a little program. The problem is that my constructor is unable to create the file that I need.

**Here is my main:**

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    createUser user = new createUser("username", "password");  

    }
```

**Here is my class:**

```
public class createUser {

private Formatter formatter;
private Scanner scanner;
private File file;
private String username;
private String password;

createUser(String username, String password){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
try{
    String path = "D:\\Users\\" + this.username +".txt";
    file = new File(path);
    formatter = new Formatter(path);                    
    scanner = new Scanner(new File(path));
    formatter.format("Username: %s\n", username);
    formatter.format("Password: %s\n", password);
    formatter.close();
    System.out.printf("%s has been created!", this.username);
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("Failed to create the account!");
}

}

}
```

**Output:**
Failed to create the account!

Comment: 1- Please use the java code conventions to create your classes, see it here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html the doc is old but still valid 2- edit your question and add where are you calling your class

Comment: @Jorge Campos Thanks, done! and I've already figured out the answer.

Comment: Create one Class to represent one Object. Don't put all fields in one class. Ideally you should have "User" class with properties related to user, and a different class, say "UserCreater" for creating the class. Class name should be a noun, not a verb. Class name should start with capital letter. Don't use the constructor to create the user file. Use the constructor to initiate the class and have a different method to create the file. these are some of the best practices.

Comment: @Tharindu Vishwanath Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I have to create the **Users** folder manually.